# std::C++ Can reading and writing asynchronously in non empty queue lead to race condition?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, producer-consumer

I am using `std::queue` for a pub-sub type system.

- The main thread pushes some data in the queue and continues (no mutex lock here)

```
// no need to acquire any lock as only the main thread inserts in the queue
queue.push(dataToLog);    
// notify the consumer thread waiting on this new available data
conditionalVariable.notify_one();
```

- The worker thread pulls out data when the conditional variable is set

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(queueMutex);
    
// put the thread to sleep till the thread is not notified in the producer code and queue is empty
conditionalVariable.wait(locker, []() {return !queue.empty();});
    
// get the data once it is available
const data * latestData = queue.front();
queue.pop();
locker.unlock();
```

my question is, is this thread safe coding given the fact that there is no lock while putting data in queue. Please note that there is a check `conditionalVariable.wait(locker, []() {return !queue.empty();});` to ensure that the consumer doesn't pop anything when queue is empty. But there might be a situation in which the main thread writes but the worker thread pulls out at the same time. Is this considered a race condition? My confusion stems from the fact that even though the queue is a shared variable between the master and the worker thread but the actual data they access i.e. the front and back of the queue are not actually shared.

Should I place locks while putting data in queue also?

Only one thread writes to the queue and only one thread (different from the one that writes) reads from the queue.

Comment: This has nothing to do with queues and everything to do with how condition variables work. You always acquire a lock for modification.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, attempting to execute a `push` and a `pop` concurrently seems to be a race condition.

Regardless of whether the front and the back of the queue are or are not actually shared, (depending on how they've chosen to implement it) the queue may easily have some internal variables that are modified by both `push` and `pop`, so executing them concurrently causes a problem.

The exact wording from the standard is:

> The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two potentially concurrent conflicting actions, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other, except for the special case for signal handlers described below. Any such data race results in undefined behavior.

Unless you can find something to say that `push` and `pop` are both atomic (which I don't see), you're executing two potentially concurrent conflicting operations, neither of which is atomic. Therefore you seem to have undefined behavior.